# MvvmCross sample projects run

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to introduce myself into the MVVMCross project, but I can not run the sample MonoDroid projects in the emulator. The WinPhone7 project run perfectly.
I get the following error during the Copying application to device process
http://snag.gy/PCY39.jpg
I tried the MonoCross sample projects, it runs correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that means that one of the Android SDK add-on libraries you are trying to use is not available on the device/emulator.  An example would be if the Google maps .jar isn't on the device and you are trying to use it.

Comment: I'd go for Google maps too - you can install that using instructions like http://3zwireless.com/Android1.html

Comment: I think I installed everything with the Android APK Manager. Here you can see what I installed. http://snag.gy/DIwWc.jpg.

Comment: You need to include the maps in the emulator as well - see the 3zwireless link above.

Answer (score 0):

I've just pushed some changes to GitHub which separate the Maps dependencies out into a separate assembly.

You will still need Maps installed (follow instructions like http://3zwireless.com/Android1.html) for the Conference sample, but Tutorial, BestSellers, TwitterSearch, SimpleDroid, and CustomerManagement should install and run on a non-mapping Emulator.